<button> is only becoming clickable once a certain option in a multiselect is clicked
I'm making a custom customer churn survey component in React with Tailwind as my styling library:
const CustomerSurvey = ({ setOpen } : CustomerSurveyProps) => {
    const [selectedReasons, setSelectedReasons] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [otherReason, setOtherReason] = useState("");

    const handleReasonChange = (reason: string) => {
        const isSelected = selectedReasons.includes(reason);
        if (isSelected) {
            setSelectedReasons(selectedReasons.filter((r) => r !== reason));
        } else {
            setSelectedReasons([...selectedReasons, reason]);
        }
    };

    const handleOtherReasonChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        setOtherReason(value);
        console.log("Other reason:", value);
    };

    const customerChurnReasonMutation = useMutation({
        mutationFn: (reason: object) => {
            return axios.post(
                backendUrl + "/customer-churn", 
                reason
            );
        },
    });

    const handleSubmitBody = async () => {
        try {
            // Create a JSON object from selectedReasons and otherReason
            const surveyData = {
                selectedReasons,
                others: selectedReasons.includes("Other") ? otherReason : "",
            };

            const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

            if (error) {
                throw error;
            }

            const body = {
                user_id: data.user.id,
                user_email: data.user.email,
                reason: surveyData,
            };

            await customerChurnReasonMutation.mutateAsync(body);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h2 className="text-xl font-bold mb-4">Let us know where we can improve on!</h2>
            <div className="mb-6">
                <p className="mb-2">We're sorry to see you go. What's your reason for unsubscribing?</p>
                <div className="space-y-2">
                    <div
                        className={`p-2 border rounded cursor-pointer ${
                            selectedReasons.includes("I no longer need the product") ? "bg-gray-200" : ""
                        }`}
                        onClick={() => handleReasonChange("I no longer need the product")}
                    >
            I no longer need the product
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`p-2 border rounded cursor-pointer ${
                            selectedReasons.includes("I found a better product") ? "bg-gray-200" : ""
                        }`}
                        onClick={() => handleReasonChange("I found a better product")}
                    >
            I found a better product
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`p-2 border rounded cursor-pointer ${
                            selectedReasons.includes("I found the product too difficult to use") ? "bg-gray-200" : ""
                        }`}
                        onClick={() => handleReasonChange("I found the product too difficult to use")}
                    >
            I found the product too difficult to use
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`p-2 border rounded cursor-pointer ${
                            selectedReasons.includes("Price is too high") ? "bg-gray-200" : ""
                        }`}
                        onClick={() => handleReasonChange("Price is too high")}
                    >
            Price is too high
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className={`p-2 border rounded cursor-pointer ${
                            selectedReasons.includes("Other") ? "bg-gray-200" : ""
                        }`}
                        onClick={() => handleReasonChange("Other")}
                    >
            Other
                    </div>
                    <div className={`mt-2 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out ${
                        selectedReasons.includes("Other")  ? "opacity-100 max-h-40" : "opacity-0 max-h-0"
                    }`}>
                        <textarea
                            className="w-full p-2 border rounded"
                            placeholder="Please provide more details"
                            value={otherReason}
                            onChange={handleOtherReasonChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button
                type="button"
                className="inline-flex w-full cursor-pointer justify-center rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
                onClick={handleSubmitBody}
            >
                    Deactivate Subscription
            </button>
        </>         
    );
};

I explicitly put cursor-pointer on the <button> tag but it's not showing and not making the button clickable. It only shows when "Other" is selected among the option pool - thus the button is also only clickable when "Other" is selected.
What seems to be the issue here?

The issue was in the rendering of the textarea. Adding an overflow-hidden solved the issue.
<div className={`mt-2 mb-4 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out overflow-hidden ${
  selectedReasons.includes("Other") ? "opacity-100 max-h-40" : "opacity-0 max-h-0"
}`}>
  <textarea
    className="w-full p-2 border rounded"
    placeholder="Please provide more details"
    value={otherReason}
    onChange={handleOtherReasonChange}
  />
</div>

